# Understanding pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn pointers in C but is getting mixed up with the following concepts:

```
char *string = "hello"
char *string2;
```

What is the main difference between:

```
A.) *string2 = string;
```

then

```
B.) string2 = "bye";
```

Comment: second one is wrong. Nothing to do with pointers, type mismatch.

Comment: Well, as long as you are learning pointers you might as well see it: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/

Comment: @diesel:  My answer (below) is more applicable to the question asked before editing, but I'm going to leave it because it covers the concept now asked fairly succinctly as well.

Answer (score 9):

Some pictures may help.

Assume the following memory map (addresses are completely arbitrary and don't reflect any known architecture):

```
Item            Address           0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----            -------           ----  ----  ----  ----
"hello"         0x00501234         'h'   'e'   'l'   'l'
                0x00501238         'o'  0x00   
"bye"           0x0050123A                     'b'   'y'
                0x0050123C         'e'  0x00  0x??   0x??
                ...
string          0x80FF0000        0x00  0x50  0x12  0x34
string2         0x80FF0004        0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

This shows the situation after the declarations.  `"hello"` and `"bye"` are string literals, stored as arrays of `char` "somewhere" in memory, such that they are available over the lifetime of the program.  Note that attempting to modify the contents of string literals invokes undefined behavior; you don't want to pass string literals (or pointer expressions like `string` that evaluate to the addresses of string literals) as arguments to functions like `scanf`, `strtok`, `fgets`, etc.

`string` is a pointer to `char`, containing the address of the string literal `"hello"`.  `string2` is also a pointer to `char`, and its value is indeterminate (`0x??` represents an unknown byte value).

When you write

```
string2 = "bye";
```

you assign the address of `"bye"` (0x0050123A) to `string2`, so our memory map now looks like this:

```
Item            Address           0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----            -------           ----  ----  ----  ----
"hello"         0x00501234         'h'   'e'   'l'   'l'
                0x00501238         'o'  0x00   
"bye"           0x0050123A                     'b'   'y'
                0x0050123C         'e'  0x00  0x??   0x??
                ...
string          0x80FF0000        0x00  0x50  0x12  0x34
string2         0x80FF0004        0x00  0x50  0x12  0x3A
```

Seems simple enough, right?

Now let's look at the statement

```
*string2 = string;
```

There are a couple of problems here.

First, a digression - declarations in C are centered around the types of *expressions*, not objects.  `string2` is a pointer to a character; to access the character value, we must *dereference* `string2` with the unary `*` operator:

```
char x = *string2;
```

The type of the *expression* `*string2` is `char`, so the declaration becomes

```
char *string2;
```

By extension, the type of the *expression* `string2` is `char *`, or pointer to `char`.

So when you write

```
*string2 = string;
```

you're attempting to assign a value of type `char *` (`string`) to an expression of type `char` (`*string2`).  That's not going to work, because `char *` and `char` are not compatible types.  This error shows up at translation (compile) time.  If you had written

```
*string2 = *string;
```

then both expressions have type `char`, and the assignment is legal.

However, if you haven't assigned anything to `string2` yet, its value is indeterminate; it contains a random bit string that may or may not correspond to a valid, writable address.  Attempting to deference a random, potentially invalid pointer value invokes undefined behavior; it may appear to work fine, it may crash outright, it may do anything in between.  This problem won't show up until runtime.  Even better, if you assigned the string literal `"bye"` to `string2`, then you run into the problem described above; you're trying to modify the contents of a string literal.  Again, that's a problem that's not going to show up until runtime.

Answer (score 3):

There are some subtle inferences being made by other answerers, missing the POV of a newbie.

```
char *string = "hello";
```

Declares a pointer variable which is initialized to point at a character array (a good type match traditionally).

The statement

```
*string = "hello";
```

dereferences what should be a pointer variable and assigns a value to the pointed location.  (It is not a variable declaration; that has to be done above it somewhere.)  However, since `string` has type `char *`—so `*string` has type `char`—and the right side of the assignment is an expression with a pointer value, there is a type mismatch. This can be fixed in two ways, depending on the intent of the statement:

```
string = "hello";     /* with "char *" expressions on both sides */
```

or

```
*string = 'h';        /* with "char" expressions on both sides */
```

The first reassigns `string` to point to memory containing a sequence of characters (`hello\000`).  The second assignment changes the character pointed to by `string` to the `char` value `h`.

Admittedly, this is a slightly confusing subject which *all* `C` programmers go through a little pain learning to grasp.  *The pointer declaration syntax has a slightly different (though related) effect than the same text in a statement.*  Get more practice and experience writing and compiling expressions involving pointers, and eventually my words will make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

AFTER EDIT:

The difference is that A) will not compile, and if it did, it's **undefined behavior**, because you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Also, please don't change your question drastically after posting it.

Answer (score 0):

`*string` can be read as "whatever `string` points to", which is a `char`. Assigning `"bye"` to it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

A C string is just an array of characters. C string literals like `"hello"` above could be viewed as "returning" a pointer to the first element of the character array, `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }`.

Thus, `char *string = "bye"` makes sense while `char string = "bye"` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`char *` is a pointer to a character. Literals such as `"hello"` returns a pointer to the first character of the string. Therefore, `string = "bye"` is meaningful making `string` point to the first character of string `"bye"`.

`*string`, on the other hand, is *the character* pointed by `string`. It's not a pointer but an 8-bit integer. This is why the assignment `*string = "bye"` is meaningless and will probably lead to a segmentation fault as the memory segment where `"bye"` stored is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

### C don't have string data type

In C `char*` is just a pointer to the (usually first) character of char array.

We don't know where you declared this variables.

If they are in a body of a function, they will be allocated on a stack.
Otherwise they will be allocated in a `.data` of `.bss` section

This expression allocates `char` pointer and initializes its value to point to a string literal "hello".
String literals are usually stored in `.rodata` section.

```
char *string = "hello"
```

This just allocates char pointer without initializing it's value. So it can point anywhere.

```
char *string2;
```

This is assignment, don't have much sense, because de-referenced `char` pointer has the value of (or operates on) single character, not string pointer:

```
*string2 = string;
```

So our assignment should be like this to have sense:

```
*string2 = 'A';
```

But this assignment is fine, meaning we assign the `char` pointer to point to a string literal "bye" allocated probably in `.rodata` section:

```
string2 = "bye";
```