# What is the difference between *ptr, &ptr, and ptr in C? When should I use one or the other?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, codeblocks

I'm learning how to use pointers in C, but my textbook doesn't do a good job explaining them.
Given a pointer `int * ptr;`  what is the difference between:

```
   ptr=
  *ptr=
  &ptr=
```

also when using scanf should I use `scanf("%d",&ptr)` or `scanf("%d",ptr)`?

Comment: "... my textbook doesn't do a good job explaining them" --> new book

Comment: try printing all 3..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C Pointers: \*ptr vs &ptr vs ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044422/c-pointers-ptr-vs-ptr-vs-ptr)

Comment: [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk) and [Understanding pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187510/understanding-pointers-in-c) also answer your question in great detail. The `scanf` part will become clear once you understand pointers in general. For `scanf`/`printf` formatting help, look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf).

Comment: @Andy_101 Yes, thank you, I don't know why I couldn't find it